# Членораздельные звуки

Tags: недопустимая-метка, фонетика

Почему в немецком языке существуют членораздельные звуки, а современная теория русского языка  их не признаёт? [Источник](http://lib.rus.ec/b/325096/read).

Comment: Мне тоже интересно, как это:"членораздельный звук"? В смысле, отдельно звук А или Э? или что подразумевается в вашем вопросе? Я так понимаю "членораздельный", значит понятный, несущий какой-то смысл, значение. А что за смысл в том же звуке А без контекста, кроме как - гласный нелабиализованный? Мы даже не можем сказать - ударный он или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Ерунда.
Ещё раз, (не)членораздельной бывает речь, т.е. поток звуков, а не звуки конкретного языка.

У Гумбольдта, на которого вы ссылаетесь, "нечленораздельные звуки" означает именно речь, звуковой поток, а не звуки какого-то языка.

Answer (score 0):

К глубокому сожалению современная русская филология пошла по ложному следу и практически преступно - небрежно пренебрегла идеями Гумбольдта и идеями И.А Болдуэна де Куртенэ.

Так вот - согласно Вильгельма Гумбольдта, любой человеческий язык отличается от остальных собственным набором членораздельных звуков. А согласно Болдуэна де Куртенэ, кроме того, что любой язык имеет своё собственное количество звуков, звуки конкретного языка имеют свою степень артикулярной пиковости, т.е. различную норму произношения. Например, русский членораздельный звук Р звучит в русской речи несколько иначе, чем  его аналог , к примеру, во французском языке или еврейком языке. Регулятором, устанавливающим норму произношения, согласно Болуэну де Куртенэ, является так называемое "народное чутьё" , которое Гумбольдт называет "языковым сознанием". 
Таким образом, существуют свои звуки языка и чужие звуки языка. Поэтому когда русский человек, допустим, слышит французскую речь, он как бы " округляет  нормы произношения "чужого языка" в нормы "своего языка".
Все звуки речи, имеющие фонетическое значение конкретного языкового сознания, подразделяются на фонемы , т.е. на смыслозначимые звуки. Фонемы отличаются друг от друга собственными дифференциальными признаками. Существуют два типа дифференциальных признаков - атрибутивные. т.е. не имеющие фонетического значения, несущественные, например, глухие, велярные, палательные, звонкие , упоминаемые Вами нелабиализованные звуки и т.д. Но помимо них существуют акцидентные дифференциальные   признаки, которые в каждом конкретном языковом значении имют своё собственное значение. Например, в русском, во многих славянских, в финно-угорских и тюркских языках акцидентными признаками обладают мягкие и твёрдые звуки, в том числе - гласные и твёрдые гласные звуки. Например, русский хорошо различает понятия слов с мягкими или твёрдыми звуками типа моль и мол, ныть или нить, щит или шить. А вот, например, для французов или немцев различие твёрдого или мягкого звука является несущественным.

Поэтому, например, в русском языке 48 членораздельных звуков. а в украинском - 50, там  узаконены ещё два звука : мягкий фрикативный Г и твёрдый фрикативный Г.

К сожалению, мои деликатные попытки каким - то образом повлиять на изменение представлений о звуковом составе русского языка, официальными представителями русской филологии нагло и безапелляционно игнорируются. Эти люди просо не понимают, что у гениальных людей имеются возможности с лёгкостью поставить на место любого невменяемого интеллигента, если он не желает понимать элементарных истин. Поэтому я пока терплю их наглые выходки. Но пусть знают - даром игнорирование здравого смысла не получится. Думаю, уже в скором времени  такое игнорирование выйдет боком .

На досуге, если кто всерьёз желает ознакомиться с научными заблуждениями современной русской филологии (разумеется, пока в усечённом, урезанном виде),  рекомендую почитать "размещённый в Интернете "Учебник для написания ученбников по русскому языку" и "Пояснительную записку к "Учебнику для написания учебников по русскому языку".

Галактиону.

Вы не предполагайте. Неужели непонятны элементарные вещи?

Хочу напомнить Вам одну вещь. В хазарских и аварских рунах мягкие и твёрдые звуки в древнее время имели различные буквы для обозначения. Их считали разными звуками. И только благодаря русскому языку, в котором, как известно, произошло разделение звуков на твёрдые и мягкие, сегодня правопреемники хазарских и аварских рун , например, кумыки, перейдя на кириллицу, стали обозначать мягкие и твёрдые звуки  одинаковыми буквами, добавляя к обозначаемым мягкие звуки буквам мягкий знак.

И какая разница, акающий или окающий диалект у представителей русского языкового сознания?

Например, согласно Ивановой, понятие "ещё" можно записать, как минимум, в 93 вариантах. 
И что?

Вы что, считаете  что в русском языке нет гласных мягких звуков? А вот И.А. Болдуэн де Куртенэ считал, что есть. Например, звук "Ы" он считал "твёрдым звуком"  "И". Более того, именно так считалось и в глаголице. А всего в русском языке 10 гласных звуков - 5 мягких и 5 твёрдых. Это помимо йотированных дифтонгов.

Comment: >Поэтому, например, в русском языке 48 членораздельных звуков. а в украинском - 50, там узаконены ещё два звука : мягкий фрикативный Г и твёрдый фрикативный Г.

Хм... это ж вроде **ещё один**, а не **ещё два**. :-)

Comment: Nikolja, даже не заморачивайтесь.
В украинском против русского нет только мягких губных и Р, зато есть мягкие Ж, Ш, Ц, твердый Щ, ДЗ, ДЖ (бджола) - это только навскидку. 

Автор не понимает разницы между буквой и звуком.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что Иван Стрельцов рассматривает множество гласных звуков русского языка как объединение:

1) множества гласных звуков, которые однозначно моделируются с помощью букв русского алфавита (таков, например, звук [o] в последнем слоге слова "молоко", однозначно моделируемый буквой "о" как окающими русскими, так и акающими русскими),

2) множества гласных звуков, которые неоднозначно моделируются с помощью букв русского языка (таковы, например, гласные звуки в первом и втором слогах слова "молоко").